# Why does sshd requires an absolute path?

Tags: security, path, executable, sshd

Why does `sshd` require an absolute path when restarting, e.g `/usr/sbin/sshd` rather than `sshd`

Are there any security implications?

P.S the error message:

```
# sshd
sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is specific to OpenSSH from version 3.9 onwards.

For every new connection, sshd will re-execute itself, to ensure that all execute-time randomisations are re-generated for each new connection. In order for sshd to re-execute itself, it needs to know the full path to itself.

Here's a quote from the release notes for 3.9:

> - Make sshd(8) re-execute itself on accepting a new connection. This security   measure ensures that all execute-time randomisations are
>     reapplied for each    connection rather than once, for the master
>     process' lifetime. This includes   mmap and malloc mappings, shared
>     library addressing, shared library mapping    order, ProPolice and
>     StackGhost cookies on systems that support such things

In any case, it is usually better to restart a service using either its init script (e.g. `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`) or using `service sshd restart`. If nothing else, it will help you verify that the service will start properly after the next reboot...

(*original answer, now irrelevant: My first guess would be that `/usr/sbin` isn't in your $PATH.*)

Comment: Of course its in $PATH, otherwise how can I get that error message  from sshd;-P

Comment: You mean the error message you didn't mention in your post?

Comment: My bad, edited the post

Answer (score 11):

This is to prevent someone from injecting a `sshd` program somewhere in one of the directories in your `PATH`
and you inadvertently executing it. This [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20181120142250/http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/other-linux-distributions/12716-ssh-problems.html) from 2004 already describes the issue.

Comment: While that post describes the issue correctly, the conclusions drawn in the thread are erroneous. It's not a bug, it's a feature :-)

Comment: @JennyD Why do you think it is a bug? I never implied that.

Comment: In the post you linked to, one response was "Bug that crept in through the upgrade to the latest openssh". None of the answers in that thread mentioned the actual reason for requiring a full path - some mentioned the same reason you do, which is very plausible and shows why it's a good idea to use the full path for any program opening login possibilities. But that is not the actual reason for this particular program having that requirement.

Comment: "`sshd` from `$PATH`" is a known security flaw, allowing Black Hat to have a different `sshd` run