# Unable to allow SSH access for new user

Tags: ssh

I currently have an issue, what I am trying to do is disable the root login and use `ssh` to login as a new user, then `su` to root when needed.

I am unable to actually allow the user to login through root. I am able to login through SSH on root, but not the user I have made.

I have used the `AllowUser` command, still no luck.

Anything there is to fix this?

I am using CentOS 07.

```
$ grep <newuser> /etc/passwd
<newuser>:x:1000:1000::/home/<newuser>:/bin/bash]


/usr/sbin/sshd -Dd
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type ECDSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 3 ECDSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-Dd'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
Cannot bind any address.
```

Comment: Please paste the output of the following commands:
1) `grep <newuser> /etc/passwd`
2) `grep <newuser> /var/log/secure`

Comment: The output of `ssh -v` (`-vv`, `-vvv`) from client and `sshd -d -oUsePrivilegeSeparation=no` (`-dd`, `-ddd`) on the remote side might also shed some light on your problem.

Comment: Added outputs on grep <newuser> /etc/passwd, grep <newuser> /var/log/secure has a tremendous amount of outputs.

.ssh -V told me I'm running OpenSSH, and OpenSSL, while sshd -D told me 
sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path

Comment: @Datsun try `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -o ...` (see [this q](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109380/why-does-sshd-requires-an-absolute-path) about absolute path).

Comment: added sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd

Comment: How are you authenticating, with a password or with a key? If it's a key, have you [checked ALL the permissions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16978/how-to-make-password-less-login-work)? Post the output of `ssh -vv user@server.example.com`.

Comment: Does the entry in `/etc/passwd` really end with `/bin/bash]`? If so, that's your problem: remove the `]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, thanks for your help guys! 
My issue was that I installed the key on root, and did not do the same for my user.
I went ahead and followed the following tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2
But making sure I was on the new user, and in the users home directory, followed ALL steps and it worked! All I had to do was import the keys, and run PuttyGen to change their settings for Putty to work!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you've forgotten to assign the user's shell?

That can be done like so:

```
useradd -s /bin/bash gdea73
```

It may be something different entirely, but I do recall making the aforementioned error myself at some point in the past.

Comment: Tried this, told me it has already been added.